# Using extern for static variables

Tags: objective-c

I'm seeing something odd when I run some code that uses the extern keyword to reference a static variable within the implementation file.  So I declare the static variable gCounter within my implementation file and reference it within two methods in the same implementation file (because its static).  However, when i use the extern keyword in my methods i get different results.  My understanding (from reading my book) is that extern isn't necessary when you're referencing a static variable declared in the same file as your methods.  Code is as follows:

/** interface **/

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Fraction : NSObject

+(Fraction *) allocF;
+(int) count;

@end

/**implementation**/

#import "Fraction.h"

static int gCounter;

@implementation Fraction

+(Fraction *) allocF
{
    extern int gCounter;
    ++gCounter;

    return [Fraction alloc];
}

+(int)count
{
    extern int gCounter;
    return gCounter;

 }

@end

/**main**/
#import "Fraction.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {

    Fraction *a, *b, *c;

    NSLog(@"The number of fractions allocated: %i", [Fraction count]);

    a = [[Fraction allocF] init];

    b = [[Fraction allocF] init];

    c = [[Fraction allocF] init];


    NSLog(@"The number of fractions allocated: %i", [Fraction count]);

    }

    return(0);

}
```

When I use the extern keyword in my methods, the code works properly and results in the integer 3 being printed.  However, when I remove extern, the integer 2 gets printed.  Why is that?  Since gCounter is a static variable, shouldn't this work without the extern keyword?

Comment: When you remove the extern, do you remove the entire declaration, or do you leave it as `int gCounter`?

Comment: @HotLicks I leave it as int gCounter.

Comment: Get rid of the entire `extern in gCounter;` lines. You don't want them if your goal is to reference the static `gCounter`.

Comment: @rmaddy that causes the program to fail

Comment: Probably because you didn't initialize `gCounter`. Try `static int gCounter = 0;`. If that doesn't solve it, then better explain what the "fail" is.

Comment: @rmaddy that doesn't do it.  But when i remove `static` it seems to work.

Comment: @rmaddy nevermind.  you were right.  stupid mistake on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between a `declaration` and a `definition`:

- `static int x` and `int x` are definitions. The compiler reserves memory for `x`.
- `extern int x` on the other hand is a declaration. You tell the compiler that there is a variable `x` that is defined somewhere else.

Also, you can define different variables in different scopes, that have the same variable name:

```
int x = 0;
{
    int x = 1;
    NSLog(@"x = %d", x); // x = 1
}
NSLog(@"x = %d", x); // x = 0
```

So if you write

```
int x;
void foo() {
    int x;
    x++;
}
```

you are incrementing the function local `x`.

```
int x;
void foo() {
    x++;
}
```

increments the global `x`

```
int x;
void foo() {
    extern int x;
    x++;
}
```

You need to declare `extern int x` if your definition of `x` is in another compilation unit, if it's in the same compilation unit, the last two are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the examples.  I used the same example from the book.  Following the example, the book says "recall that the extern declarations are not required in the two methods because the gCounter variable is defined within the file."  whats up with that?

Comment: `extern` declares a variable, that is defined in a different compilation unit (e.g. a different .m file). If you define a global variable and use it in the same file, the compiler will find it's definition.